# IBAction not processing with ScrollView and UIView

Tags: xcode, uiview

After many hours of banging my head against a wall, I think I understand why I have the problem at hand, but have not found an explanation at my level of understanding to help me resolve it. I am new to Xcode and UIKit.

I have a structure:   
   ViewController
   ScrollView    
   UIView (the content and button are on this view)

I've used the Object Library and have not written the code to generate any of the views nor objects. All of the many, and varied solutions that I've read assume that code was written extensively. I have a button on UIView that I have connected to my code 1) I can see that the button is working when I press it on my phone, but 2) the IBAction code does not fire. I think the problem is that with the button on UIView and the IBAction code connected to ViewController, something is not working correctly between the layers. I ultimately want the button to open a URL, but for simplicity in troubleshooting, I'm just printing to the debug area. I attached a screenshot of my project and a screenshot of the View Hierarchy in the event that is helpful.
(My apologies in advance wherein I have not used the correct technical language.)

Many thanks.
 [View Heirarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXGeI.jpg)
[Project Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCNeo.jpg)